# PHP Form Post to MySQL database error

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a working form on my site that successfully inserts the fields into a MySQL database table.  I added a new table, basically copied the existing code for the new form, and am getting an error.  I've tweaked it a bunch and am baffled.

Here's the form:

```
    <form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />

<fieldset>
    <label>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" required="" /> </label><br />
    <label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" required /> </label><br />
    <label>Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" required /> </label><br />
    <label>Anniversary Date: <input type="date" name="weddingdate" /> </label><br />
    <label>Birthday: <input type="date" name="birthday"  /> </label><br />
    <label>Business Name: <input type="text" name="business" /> </label><br />
    <label>Are You A Chamber Member?: <input type="radio" name="chamber" value="memyes">Yes   <input type="radio" name="chamber" value="memno"> No<br />
    <label>Comments: <input type="textarea" name="comments" rows="2" cols="50"> </label>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Enter Me In The Contest!" />
</form>
```

The contact.php file looks like this:

```
    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
include('dbconnect.php');

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$weddingdate = $_POST['weddingdate'];
$birthday = $_POST['birthday'];
$business = $_POST['business'];
$chamber = $_POST['chamber'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO contest (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `weddingdate`, `birthday`,`business`, 'chamber', 'comments') VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$weddingdate', '$birthday', '$business', '$chamber', '$comments')";

if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert)) {
    die('Error adding to database');    
}
header('Location: website omitted');
}
```

I know that it connects properly, I'm using the same connection script for both, and did a test of the connection adding a connection echo message.

All I get with this script is the "Error adding to database" message...

Thanks in advance for the advice and help!

Comment: @skrilled, instead of snark, try educating the user on what he's doing wrong.

Comment: @castis I wish I could thumb up a comment more than once. I really dislike 'I'm the God of Programming and all who know less deserve worse' kind of poeple

Comment: It's not always a good idea to use a hidden field as an `isset`. You risk in getting empty data. You're best to name your submit button and use `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`

Comment: what does mysqli_error tell you?

Comment: castis: well i'm tired of typing out "sanitize your database input" every 5 minutes on this site. are we assuming OP has no clue how to google? little bobby tables = first result on google.

Comment: I think you can pick out certain inconsistencies in your code by yourself.

Comment: Plus you quoted two of your (`INSERT into`) columns `'chamber', 'comments'` which should be backticks as you did for the others.

Comment: @OP Learn how to error check. if (!mysqli_query(...) { die(mysqli_error()); } will tell you all the failures in your code.

Comment: @skrilled MarcT clearly put a modicum of effort into his question. there are definitely still users out there that don't know any better due to super old tutorials that are still floating around. Best case would have been to point to an answered question that outlines the error of his ways so that he can learn.

Comment: @castis no no, beating down the uneducated masses is the only way to go. How else would you thrive?? Besides, looking smarter makes you smarter

Comment: Ya'll might think about moving this to conversation?

Comment: If I had a dollar for every person who held my hand and explained documentation for me, I'd have zero dollars. I guess I expect too much :p OP did formulate his question well. I APOLOGIZE.

Comment: so skrilled, we can't compete. @Nazca that's what a list of comments is.

Comment: I see that I unjustly expected more from StackOverflow users. my apologies on assuming you all were competent.

Comment: @Rottingham I guess?  I thought the comments here was intended to supplement the answer as opposed to arguing about the intent or structure of the post or answers or w/e.

Comment: I believe you can leave me out of that comment. @castis where I do believe mine were constructive ;-) *"I see that I unjustly expected more from StackOverflow users. my apologies on assuming you **all** were competent."*

Comment: Fred I've seen you all over the place helping tons of people, we don't even know each other and I look up to you lol.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the kind words. @castis I'm not the best, but I do have my moments ;-) Cheers

Comment: This is the recommended method `$firstname=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$_POST['firstname']);` (do the same for the rest) and use backticks throughout your entire `INSERT` columns. That will fix your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two of your `INSERT` columns (`chamber` and `comments`) had single quotes instead of backticks.

```
(.......`weddingdate`, `birthday`,`business`, 'chamber', 'comments')
                                              ^       ^  ^        ^
```

The method you're presently using for your inputs is unsafe, so that's been replaced by incorporating the [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) function.

`$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];` (**not** recommended)

`$firstname= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['firstname']);` (recommended)

**N.B.:** It's not always a good idea to use a hidden field to check if it is `isset` - You risk in getting empty data without checking for empty fields, which you're not doing.

You could rather name your submit button and use if `(isset($_POST['submit']))`

For example:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter Me In The Contest!" />
```

yet, that's entirely up to you.

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
include('dbconnect.php');

$firstname= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['lastname']);
$email= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['email']);
$weddingdate= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['weddingdate']);
$birthday= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['birthday']);
$business= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['business']);
$chamber= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['chamber']);
$comments= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['comments']);


$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO `contest` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `weddingdate`, `birthday`,`business`, `chamber`, `comments`) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$weddingdate', '$birthday', '$business', '$chamber', '$comments')";

if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert)) {
    die('Error adding to database');    
}
header('Location: website omitted');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick education.  It was definitely the Back-Ticks that had me messed up. I'm new still to the PHP side of things, and appreciate the extra help on my code.  I've successfully used this script and am adjusting the other PHP form connection script I am using currently to match it for the security reasons mentioned.

Comment: I would have UP voted, but I'm new enough to this site to not be able at the moment.

Comment: You're welcome and glad I could help and pass on the education at the same time. The Web is not the friendly place that many think it is and we need to protect ourselves. @MarcT

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes from around your column names like this:

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO contest (firstname, lastname, email, weddingdate, birthday,business, chamber, comments) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$weddingdate', '$birthday', '$business', '$chamber', '$comments')";
```

Comment: It's best to keep the backticks around the column names. FYI: I'm NOT the downvoting type, just in case someone does it to you. I sure don't like it myself but hey... they're only points and they're not real. If you stand by your convictions, then let it ride ;-) Cheers --- You're theoretically correct, but again... backticks are best and for so many reasons.

Comment: Hey no problems. That's why I said "try" :) I guess I should have done a little more research before answering. Lesson learnt :)

Comment: I like to "share the wealth" as it were. ;-)

Comment: I didn't know any better than the next guy many months ago, so it pleases me to share what I know that has been **"tried, tested, and true"**, and I learn most of it right here on SO. Mind you, Google is an indispensible tool.

Comment: In theory, my answer may still solve the problem given the backticks are not used on the business and chamber columns. Maybe.

Comment: We'll just sit and wait, and see what comes of it. When I give an answer, and I know where the bugs and potential bugs are, will point them out. It's all about "success" and "security" ;-) As the saying goes: "Never trust user input"; NEVER.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I want to say this little warning to you: your script is screaming "I'm open for SQL injections." You've no protection at all.

Always use at least addslashes....

---// your script (adjusted) //-----

```
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
        include('dbconnect.php');

        $firstname = addslashes($_POST['firstname']);
        $lastname = addslashes($_POST['lastname']);
        $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
        $weddingdate = addslashes($_POST['weddingdate']);
        $birthday = addslashes($_POST['birthday']);
        $business = addslashes($_POST['business']);
        $chamber = addslashes($_POST['chamber']);
        $comments = addslashes($_POST['comments']);

        $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO contest (firstname, lastname, email, weddingdate,
 birthday, business, chamber, comments) VALUES 
('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."', '".$weddingdate."', 
                    '".$birthday."', '".$business."', '".$chamber."', '".$comments."')";


            if(mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert)){

                echo "Query &nbsp;done :-)<br>";
            } else {
                echo mysqli_error($dbcon) . "<hr>";
            }

        }
```

---// your script (adjusted) //-----

You can, of course also use mysqli_real_escape_string instead of using addslashes:

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$sqlinsert);
```

Anyway, if you run this script and you run into an MySQL error then the script will send an error message to your screen. You can take it up from there ;-)

P.s. your script isn't working because of the way you've defined your fields in your query: you use : `business`, and 'chamber' together in  the field names....

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the quick education. It was definitely the Back-Ticks that had me messed up. I'm new still to the PHP side of things, and appreciate the extra help on my code. I've successfully used this script and am adjusting the other PHP form connection script I am using currently to match it for the security reasons mentioned.